# Is it duplicate content to post content into social networks?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, social-media, google-image-search

In my website, whenever I publish an article, I post that article with its corresponding image to Facebook and Google Plus.

1. Is it duplicate content and penalty happens?
2. And when someone searches the title of the article, which article does Google show? One in my website or one in my G+ account?
3. The same question happens for images. When someone searches the title of the article in Google Image, which image is shown in the SERP? One in my website or one in my G+ account? (I know images in Facebook aren't indexed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you post with exactly same text and images then you should avoid doing that. Instead just share the link on social media with one to 2 line message. Also, as a good SEO practice, you should focus on good length content on your website and just share the link on social media.
2. Google algorithm takes several factors into consideration to identify duplicate content like where the post was first visible, back link and trust factor etc. So, it's hard to say where it may show up. Generally, G+ gets indexed very quickly but it's hard to say which would rank first.
3. Images don't have much duplicate content issue but still recommended to have your own image which is related to the content. With regards to ranking its same like point 2. Google takes several factors into consideration to rank images and its hard to say which would show up first.

Comment: One technique is to post either a snippet or shorter version of the post on sites that are not yours. You are right to mention that the whole post should not be copied. I am not a fan of Facebook or Google+. There is value to Google+ that does not exist elsewhere and I understand that for some users, Facebook is their portal of choice. Still, I am finding that for ranking within Google, posting articles on Facebook and Google+ has limited effect. The primary exception is building authority with Google+ or Google My Business.